# Extending model without persisting to datastore

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The below shows Ember files from an application that lists employee names from a Mirage data store.

What I need to do is add a property 'present' to the model outside of the datastore. The idea is that the employee will click their name on the list to toggle whether they are present or not.

What I don't know is how or where to apply this functionality.

Any advice is welcome.

**Mirage Scenario**

```
export default function(server) {
  server.create('employee', {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
  });
  server.create('employee', {
    firstname: "Joe",
    lastname: "Bloggs"
  });
}
```

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('employee');
  }
});
```

**Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstname: DS.attr('string'),
  lastname: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |employee|}}
      <li>{{employee.firstname}} {{employee.lastname}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to persist the changes to the store, don't you want to save them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ember computed.

```
//model.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstname: DS.attr('string'),
  lastname: DS.attr('string'),

  present: Ember.computed('firstname', 'lastname', function(){
    return Ember.isPresent(this.get('firstname')) && Ember.isPresent(this.get('lastname'));
  })
});
```